# C/C++ custom allocator memory leak

Tags: c++, stl, containers, shared-ptr, allocator

I create a custom memory allocator like following:

```
class pool_allocator
{
    // required methods
    // ...
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<MemoryChunks> m_t;
};
```

The purpose of this allocator is to share memory allocating by different container and only deallocate them when all container and deleted. therefore, I use `boost::shared_ptr`.

However after running it in VS2008, I detect a memory leak. I don't know why.

If I change `boost::shared_ptr` to `MemoryChunks`, the memory leak goes away.

Comment: MemoryChunks just like a array of Chunk, each chunk contains a array of objects, and a ptr to the next free object. Since object is never freed unless the Chunk is deleted. allocate/free means O(1). when Memory chunks is deleted, it will free all the chunks.

Comment: You better post the definition of `MemoryChunk`, and if possible the implementation of the allocator itself. Are you handling rebings properly? Does it just work if I feed a container a default constructed allocator? etc...

Comment: @K-ballo thanks. the allocator is part of another library: [pool_allocator_stl](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184406243). I add a new holding policy, which is using boost::shared_ptr to hold them. If I using their default holding policy, no memory leak detected on the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware that allocators are treated as stateless in C++03? Try using your allocator in conjuntion with Boost.Containers (It was just accepted, but I think they are already part of Boost.Interprocess), which respects allocators. Not easy to say anything else without the definition for `MemoryChunks`.

Comment: MemoryChunks just like a array of Chunk, each chunk contains a array of objects, and a ptr to the next free object. Since object is never freed unless the Chunk is deleted. allocate/free means O(1). when Memory chunks is deleted, it will free all the chunks.